# R question: How to address (select) <NA> column from result of `table` function with `useNA`?

Tags: r

When you supply `useNA` to the `table` function, you get a column named `<NA>`. Is there a way to address that column?

Example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'magrittr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     set_names
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     extract
df = data.frame(A=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), B=c('p', 'q', 'p', 'q', 'p', 'q'))
df
#>   A B
#> 1 a p
#> 2 a q
#> 3 a p
#> 4 b q
#> 5 b p
#> 6 b q
df %>% table()
#>    B
#> A   p q
#>   a 2 1
#>   b 1 2
df[1,2] = NA
df %>% table()
#>    B
#> A   p q
#>   a 1 1
#>   b 1 2
df %>% table(useNA='ifany')
#>    B
#> A   p q <NA>
#>   a 1 1    1
#>   b 1 2    0
tab = df %>% table(useNA='ifany')
tab[, 'q']
#> a b 
#> 1 2
tab[, '<NA>']
#> Error in `[.default`(tab, , "<NA>"): subscript out of bounds
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a character `"NA"`

```
colnames(tab)
#[1] "p" "q" NA
```

So, we can use the function which can find the `NA` elements

```
tab[, is.na(colnames(tab))]
#a b 
#1 0
```

Comment: How weird. They used an actual `NA` value as the column name.

Comment: @abalter  it is the print format which is misleading